# How to reset azure AD password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a free trial account, not sure if this is the problem

I created an azure AD user with my Hotmail account using this format 
@examplehotmail.onmicrosoft.com

when I try to reset the password, the reset button is greyed out (disabled)

how do I reset the password to receive the first temporary password?

Comment: Reset password via new portal or classic portal?

Comment: new portal. the button is there but is disabled

Comment: I have this problem too.  User was created via Subscription -> IAM -> Add (which probably doesn't involve Active Directory?)